# Extending an Objective-C program with a scripting language

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, interpreter

Is there a ready-made implementation of an interpreter for ObjC.  Basically, I need my program to be extendable via a scripting language.

I'm not sure if this is already provided by some kind of framework, or perhaps I can implement AppleScript internally - not sure how I would do that tho.  It seems to only apply to automating the program itself, not for extending its own functionality.

Something similar to mIRC's means of interfacing with a scripting language.

Comment: How about Javascript via JavaScriptCore?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You bet there is. It's called [FScript](http://www.fscript.org/); it's open-source and includes a console with a REPL in which you can interact with Cocoa objects. The syntax is Smalltalk-like, which is very similar to Objective-C -- the main difference is no square brackets. Here's some snippets from their tutorial. Notice that variables don't have to be explicitly typed!

```
> imageLocation := NSURL fileURLWithPath:'/Library/Desktop Pictures/Nature/Clown Fish.jpg'.

> image := CIImage imageWithContentsOfURL:imageLocation.

> image drawInRect:(200<>80 extent:600<>400) fromRect:image extent operation:NSCompositeSourceOver fraction:1.
```

You will be interested in their [Embedding FScript Into Cocoa Applications Guide](http://www.fscript.org/documentation/EmbeddingFScriptIntoCocoa/index.htm).

Answer (score 2):

Do you just want your program to be scriptable? If so, then you should probably add AppleScript support. See [Introduction to Cocoa Scripting Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ScriptableCocoaApplications/SApps_intro/SAppsIntro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001982-BCICHGIE) for information on how to do this.

Comment: Hmm.  I don't think this is it.  The scripting appears to be only one-way.  That is, the script runs commands on the application, but the application doesn't interact with the script to run functions, callbacks, etc.

Comment: No, it's two-way. Look at the `NSApplescript` object. Having scripts call your program is just more complicated than having your program call scripts, so that direction dominates the document. All Mac products should support Applescript; it's part of being a good Mac app. But if you want an extensive plugin architecture, you'll want to support the Python or Ruby bridges Mark mentions. Applescript is a lousy language IMO. All that said, Cocoa Scripting (OSA) is language-agnostic. It's based on Apple Events. You can bridge to almost any scripting language.

Answer (score 2):

[Python and Ruby](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/RubyPythonCocoa/Articles/RubyPythonMacOSX.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005423-SW1) can interact with the Objective C calls so you can use them to extend the program's functionality.

Comment: Also look at MacRuby, and search for "Scripting Bridge" which is the underlying technology you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Objective C is not a scripting language, so it has no interpreter. It can only be compiled to machine codes.

If you want to use scripting language is suggest Lua. It is really easy and lightweight but still very powerful. You can use it with you native C/C++ programs and there are also ObjC bindings.

Anyway any scripting language (Python, Lua, AppleScript etc.) is built on top of some native programming language (usually C or C++) and if you want to extend your program with new features you still need to implement them first using native language.

Fot you to start: [how to bind Lua](http://cc.byexamples.com/2008/07/06/calling-c-function-from-lua-implement-sleep-function/). It is for C++, but it is the same for C and ObjC (as it is a superset of C)